# Weird insertion from Vim on mouse click

Tags: vim, putty

I'm using putty (on windows 7) to connect to shell and Vim as editor. I also have mouse=a option enabled in Vim, but I get some strange behavior (such as random insertions of characters and/or linebreaks) when I click to the right side of the Vim window (let's say it's like 70%+ of the screen width area where it gets weird). I'm slowly getting used to such behavior, but I'd really like to know if I could somehow fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure, as mouse usage mode is enabled only in Vim and I use nothing else but screen and Vim.

Comment: @kK-Storm I suspect it is a putty mouse emulation vs. termcaps thing. As such I expect the same/similar behaviour when you do `se mouse-=a`

Comment: So does this mean there isn't any solution to this problem?

Comment: @kK-Storm It means you should try the suggestions/answer the requests for more information, mostly. Next step: http://superuser.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems "the original xterm mouse protocol as implemented by PuTTY only supports mouse coordinates up to 223" [ak2 told me on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/413351/weird-insertion-from-vim-on-mouse-click#comment471871_413351). So for anyone who will face such problem - set PuTTY window size to 95 columns - and mouse will work just as expected everywhere.